# Should there be a comma in "Tell <name> <other name> says hi."?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I just wrote to someone,

> Tell Alivia Wyatt says hi.

Am I missing a comma?  It seems like there almost has to be one between the names.  I find it a strange sentence to punctuate.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sentence, and it doesn't need any punctuation. If OP is discomfitted by the two consecutive nouns, he can just put **that** in between them.

Comment: FumbleFingers, why did you write a comment instead of an answer that can be voted on and accepted?

Comment: I write too many answers already. People can upvote my comment if they agree with it, and I certainly don't mind if anyone (including you!) just cut the text and paste it as an answer - I'd even upvote that myself if there wasn't a better answer within a few hours!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If it's a good answer and the OP wants to accept it as *the* answer, then why not just post as an answer?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: For the reasons I just gave. Plus the fact that I'd just noticed I've already hit the daily 200-upvote limit. But I don't see why someone else shouldn't collect the points if it *is* a good answer, and they recognise it as such. You, for example, could have already done that by now. In which case presumably everyone would be happy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Nah, I'm not going to pinch someone else's answer. You wrote it first, it's yours (though it if is going to be an answer, I'd include a reference citing this lack of a comma as OK)! ;) So what if you hit the 200 limit for the day? The point of this site is to help answer people's questions, not to get the most points. The site is less useful when questions are properly answered in comments rather than proper answers.

Comment: "Tell John Wayne said hi."

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: IMHO the site is *more* useful if more people actively contribute answers, upvotes, comments, and edits. The more rep points one has, the easier it is to do that, so to an extent I would actually *prefer* someone else to grab them on this question. Even more so given that I personally *can't* collect any more today!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A comma would not make sense there, but using "that" in between Alivia and Wyatt would provide the separation that you are perceiving is needed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers didn't realize you'd already said the same exact thing in the comments, if you want to answer down here and claim your sweet, sweet rep points I'll delete this answer.

Comment: If FumbleFingers wanted to claim the rep for his answer, he should have posted it as an answer. :D

Comment: I'm quite happy with this answer. The only point I can see anywhere on this page that's worth adding to it is the one made by @TLP's incisive comment *"Tell John Wayne said hi."* Unless I'm much mistaken, it's the two consecutive nouns that are bothering OP, and that variation seems a really good way of calling attention to the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  "That" is definitely better to use in writing.  In person we can alliterate to make the intention clear.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple imperative statement, with the implied subject "you", the verb "tell", indirect object "Alivia", and direct object "Wyatt says hi".

In this case, one would not use a comma between the two names. Consider an equivalently structured sentence.

> Throw me the ball.

Where

> Tell -> Throw
>   Alivia -> me
>   Wyatt says hi -> the ball

We would not write

> Throw me, the ball.

as this would seem to say that I am the ball, and you should throw me.

Putting a comma between the two names would change the meaning, and would seem to say "Tell Alivia (something, probably specified in the previous sentence), because/and Wyatt says hi."

This is a more complicated issue than most simple commands, because the object is both an entire sentence on its own, and a direct quote.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried, you could put quotes round Wyatt says hi.  Compare:

> He said "Wyatt says hi"
>    He said that Wyatt says hi

Come to that, you could also put quotes round hi, as it's reported speech.